Visual Studio related error when pip installing some python libraries
There are a few Python libraries that I am trying to install such as pycld2 and spacy_hunspell but both produce the the same following error. I read on SO that I need to install some Visual Studio Build tools, which I think I have done but to no avail:

I also tried:

pip uninstall setuptools
pip install setuptools

If it matters, I'm working from a Pipenv environment in a OneDrive folder.
pycld2 and spacy_hunspell Error:
Building wheel for hunspell (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [4 lines of output]
      D:\OneDrive\Projects\.venv\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\extension.py:139: UserWarning: Unknown Extension options: 'compile_args', 'macros'
        warnings.warn(msg)
      b"T\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00s\x00y\x00s\x00t\x00e\x00m\x00 \x00c\x00a\x00n\x00n\x00o\x00t\x00 \x00f\x00i\x00n\x00d\x00 \x00t\x00h\x00e\x00 \x00p\x00a\x00t\x00h\x00 \x00s\x00p\x00e\x00c\x00i\x00f\x00i\x00e\x00d\x00.\x00\r\x00\n\x00The system cannot find the path specified.\r\n*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00*\x00

{about 200 more lines of *\x00 here}

      error: Error executing cmd /u /c "D:\Programs\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x86_amd64 && set
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for hunspell
  Running setup.py clean for hunspell
Successfully built spacy_hunspell
Failed to build hunspell
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (hunspell)

If I try installing pycld3 instead, I get this different error:
Collecting pycld3
  Using cached pycld3-0.22.tar.gz (726 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: pycld3
  Building wheel for pycld3 (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [33 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zoh7kbeq\pycld3_a58823cbcc3c4a74a320a55218fcb726\setup.py", line 173, in <module>
          setup(
        File "D:\OneDrive\Projects\.venv\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 117, in setup
          return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "D:\OneDrive\Projects\.venv\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 183, in setup
          return run_commands(dist)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "D:\OneDrive\Projects\.venv\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 199, in run_commands
          dist.run_commands()
        File "D:\OneDrive\Projects\.venv\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 954, in run_commands
          self.run_command(cmd)
        File "D:\OneDrive\Projects\.venv\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 950, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "D:\OneDrive\Projects\.venv\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 973, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "D:\OneDrive\Projects\.venv\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\bdist_wheel.py", line 398, in run
          self.run_command("build")
        File "D:\OneDrive\Projects\.venv\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 316, in run_command
          self.distribution.run_command(command)
        File "D:\OneDrive\Projects\.venv\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 950, in run_command
          super().run_command(command)
        File "D:\OneDrive\Projects\.venv\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 973, in run_command
          cmd_obj.run()
        File "C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-zoh7kbeq\pycld3_a58823cbcc3c4a74a320a55218fcb726\setup.py", line 109, in run
          raise RuntimeError(
      RuntimeError: The Protobuf compiler, `protoc`, which is required for building this package, could not be found.
      See https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf for information on installing Protobuf.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycld3
  Running setup.py clean for pycld3
Failed to build pycld3
ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (pycld3)

For this error, I tried to no avail:

pip install protobuf-compiler
pip install pyproject.toml

.
